# GAM performance and optimization

Tags: r, optimization, data-modeling, smoothing, gam

I've made a gam in R and I'm confused by the model performance parameters and smoothing optimization. The original model performs moderately well, with an r-squared of 0.428 and deviance explained = 49.4%.

I've basically just messed around with some of the model parameters to see what happens, and I found that I can improve model performance by manually setting the smoothing parameter (sp). For example, if I manually set the sp of each variable to 10,  model performance increases to an r-squared value of 0.443 and deviance explained of 55.6%. If I set sp = 1, the r-squared goes up to 0.457 and deviance explained goes up to 61.3%. It's strange to me that reducing sp improves model performance.

Have I done something wrong? Or, is there a way to optimize model performance by smoothness? I thought that gam() in the mgcv package did this already, so seems like it is being optimized by other parameters?

A second issue is that a quick check shows that model variables exhibit a high degree of concurvity ( > 0.8)

```
> concurvity(test.GAM2, full = T)
                 para    s(SST)    s(CHL)    s(HCI) s(RECRUIT)
worst    7.188075e-17 0.8348276 0.8585678 0.8209738  0.8456792
observed 7.188075e-17 0.5177076 0.6261017 0.7211087  0.4340194
estimate 7.188075e-17 0.5144364 0.5612536 0.6663378  0.4457707
```

but the pairwise comparison shows that none of the pairs of variables are the specific source

```
> concurvity(test.GAM2, full = F)
$worst
                   para       s(SST)       s(CHL)       s(HCI)   s(RECRUIT)
para       1.000000e+00 1.424905e-20 2.499486e-25 3.075670e-26 2.992960e-17
s(SST)     1.424910e-20 1.000000e+00 4.077612e-01 4.900464e-01 3.525303e-01
s(CHL)     2.493897e-25 4.077612e-01 1.000000e+00 4.216883e-01 4.302640e-01
s(HCI)     3.048747e-26 4.900464e-01 4.216883e-01 1.000000e+00 4.670733e-01
s(RECRUIT) 2.992961e-17 3.525303e-01 4.302640e-01 4.670733e-01 1.000000e+00

$observed
                   para       s(SST)       s(CHL)       s(HCI)   s(RECRUIT)
para       1.000000e+00 3.438333e-36 3.497510e-33 1.086260e-33 8.207928e-28
s(SST)     1.424910e-20 1.000000e+00 1.450778e-01 2.408831e-01 2.047249e-01
s(CHL)     2.493897e-25 3.139618e-01 1.000000e+00 2.897761e-01 1.709202e-01
s(HCI)     3.048747e-26 3.582142e-01 2.625319e-01 1.000000e+00 1.220109e-01
s(RECRUIT) 2.992961e-17 1.506172e-01 3.589984e-01 3.562581e-01 1.000000e+00

$estimate
                   para       s(SST)       s(CHL)       s(HCI)   s(RECRUIT)
para       1.000000e+00 3.901857e-23 1.190203e-27 1.412707e-28 1.358304e-20
s(SST)     1.424910e-20 1.000000e+00 1.552033e-01 2.157383e-01 2.327213e-01
s(CHL)     2.493897e-25 2.926572e-01 1.000000e+00 2.623654e-01 1.355397e-01
s(HCI)     3.048747e-26 3.069267e-01 2.177759e-01 1.000000e+00 1.447574e-01
s(RECRUIT) 2.992961e-17 1.399866e-01 3.047102e-01 3.284273e-01 1.000000e+00
```

I've made the assumption that because the pairwise comparison didn't show a high degree of concurvity between any two variables specifically, that the model results are ok. Is this correct?

For completeness, here is the rest of my code. Variables that have been commented out are those that were cut during backwards stepwise reduction.

```
test.GAM2 <- gam(SUM_RETAINED_NUM ~ #s(ANGLER_TRIPS) +
              #s(BEUTI) + 
              s(SST) + 
              s(CHL) + 
              s(HCI) +  
              #s(PDO) +
              s(RECRUIT),
             sp = c(10, 10, 10, 10),
            data = testerino4,
            family = Gamma(link = "inverse"),
            method = "REML")

summary(test.GAM2)
qqnorm(test.GAM2$residuals)
qqline(test.GAM2$residuals)
normal <- shapiro.test(residuals(test.GAM2))
normal
gam.check(test.GAM2)

# Check for concurvity
concurvity(test.GAM2, full = T)

> test.GAM2$formula
SUM_RETAINED_NUM ~ s(SST) + s(CHL) + s(HCI) + s(RECRUIT)
```